# Help me unpack this Classical Greek word?

Tags: etymology, greek, morphological-analysis

ἁλιπτοίητος

Liddell and Scott seem somewhat uncertain how this links to other Greek words, though they affirm the reading as "driven by fear across the sea."

My Greek is rusty, and I don't know that I was ever much good at breaking out the root-words joined together here.

I have looked for philological and etymological entries, but found nothing much beyond LNS reiterated.

Can anyone unpack this word?

Comment: This is perfectly good question about etymology. I do understand why anyone has objected to it.

Answer (score 2):

The first stem is ἁλι- derives from the word ἁλς meaning "sea" or generally the water close to the shore. Then you have πτοίᾱ which means "terror, fright, fear".

Comment: Right, and it's almost certainly a learned nonce-coinage by Nonnus, who seems to be the only writer who's ever used it.

Answer (score 0):

Literally, ἅλς means ‘salt’ (with which it is cognate), but it is used metaphorically for ‘sea’. In compounds the stem is ἁλι-, by analogy to the –i stems.